# Return Results of SQLAlchemy Search Query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the results to a `SQLAlchemy` query. I know that if I loop over the query I can put the results in a list (like below), but this seems inefficient for a large set of results and looks ugly when the result will be a single number (as below). Is there a more direct and/or efficient way to return query results?

```
mylist = []
for item in session.query(func.max(mytable.id)):
    mylist.append(item)
```

Comment: Return results to what exactly? Do you need indexing, or us looping enough? What do you mean by *looks ugly* for a single result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looping through the result, as you do, is correct. You can also use [`all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars) to get the list of sequences (rows). Maybe more efficient is to not store the data in a list, get smaller result sets, and/or do the operation immediately on each row. You could also use a server side cursor if your DBMS supports it.

When only one row with one field is fetched, you can use [`first()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars) and get the first element of the returned sequence. Code wise, this is probably most efficient:

```
maxid_mytable = session.query(func.max(mytable.id)).first()[0]
```

Comment: This would be neater in the instance of a single result, but would not work with n > 1.

Comment: @Michael then you just used `.all()` like @geertjanvdk suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This will the equivalent

```
mylist = session.query(func.max(mytable.id)).all()
```